# selfwritten xml generator doesnt listen to the xml output

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a page containing the following:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// Set de format van het xml document
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$test = $xml->createElement('test');
$xml->appendChild($test);
$test->createElement('name','pierre');

XMLController::CreateTestXML($xml);
```

I have written 2 functions.

1.) CreateMultipleElements() 
2.) CreateTestXML()

CreateTestXML() function contains: 
This function is meant to be adding something to the xml and it does:

```
public static function CreateTestXML(&xml){
    $objectArray = self::CreateMultipleElements(
            $xml, 
            array(
                "Persoon" => null,
                "Paard" => "Wit"
            ),
            $parent = null, 
            $attributes = array(
                "Persoon" => array(
                    "Type" => "NPS"
                )
            )
        );
}
```

Then we have the function who actually creates the nodes and the elements which is working properly:

```
public static function CreateMultipleElements(&$xml,$objectNameValue,$parent = null, $attributes = null){
        $xmlObjecten = array();
        foreach($objectNameValue as $objectName => $nodeValue){
            $object = $xml->createElement($objectName,$nodeValue);
            if(isset($attributes[$objectName])){
                foreach($attributes[$objectName] as $key => $value){
                    $object->setAttribute($key,$value);
                }
            }
            if($parent === null){
                $xmlObjecten[$objectName] = $xml->appendChild($object);
            }
            else{
                $xmlObjecten[$objectName] = $parent->appendChild($object);
            }
        }
        return $xmlObjecten;
    }
```

The xml output would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <name>pierre</name>
</test>
<persoon type="NPS"></persoon><paard>wit</paard>
```

So it seems like the generated part is ignoring the format output please help

Comment: You are calling your static method with no parameter, while they require `$xml` as their 1st parameter. Note that objects are passed by ref, so no need for a `&`

Comment: @Xenos That parameter is there, i wrote the code i wrote agian cause of personal information that cant be lacked

Comment: @Xenos also thanks for the note didnt konw that stupid me

Comment: Is this real code? `&xml` must be an error.

Comment: The & is not there anymore, &$xml makes is a reference but as the guy above said, objects are always passed by reference so no, its no error and its gone now cause its already a reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: @RoyStijsiger It must be a typo because it's attempting to pass a **constant** as function parameter. It's normally hard to diagnose a problem like this with pseudo code or redacted code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its not a constant... its a reference value.. you're making a reference to the already existing variable and using that one instead of making a new one. I could tell you more about this.. but its valid believe me.. You probably never worked with reference variables.

If you want to konw more about this let me know

Comment: @RoyStijsiger I can believe you but [the PHP interpreter seems to disagree](https://3v4l.org/1f4f9).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid: it cannot have multiple root nodes. You must only have one node (ie `<test>`).

The behavior for multiple root nodes in a XML is certainly undefined, hence the "partially formatted output".

Comment: Edit:in our real thing we have one root. The problem is it doesnt take the output layout

Comment: @RoyStijsiger Then show "your real thing" (I'm gonna regret this comment...)

Comment: Its just one root with inside off use in this functions